# How to compute sum of series until the sum stops changing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum, series

I want to compute the sum of the following series in Matlab:

[image]

I am using this MATLAB function:

```
>> syms i;
>> S = symsum((0.5^i*sin(i))/i^2, i, 0, Inf)
```

The problem is that I want to stop adding terms when the sum stops changing. For example, condition of when to stop might be that difference between sum at step `i` step and sum at step `i+1` is not larger than some user-defined tolerance `10^-8`. How can I include this condition in the above sum computation?

Comment: Note that this function `f(x) = 0.5^x/x^2*sin(x)` is not monotonic. For instance `f(14)>f(13)` and `f(20)>f(19)`. A solution is to ignore sine term and consider `g(x) = 0.5^x/x^2` for checking against tolerance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally not use the Symbolic Math Toolbox and prefer to use a simple loop instead.  Specifically, I would do this numerically and incrementally add terms to the series until the condition you speak of is satisfied.  BTW, your sum starts at `i=0`, but when `i=0`, the summation is undefined (you have a `0/0` undefined division result).  I assume you meant to start at `i=1` instead.

Something like this comes to mind:

```
s = 0;
s_before = realmax;
tol = 1e-8;
ii = 0;

while (abs(s_before - s) >= tol)
    ii = ii + 1;
    s_before = s;
    s = s + ((0.5^ii)*sin(ii))/(ii^2);        
end
```

The first four lines of code are used for setup.  `s` contains the final sum and `s_before` contains the sum from the previous iteration.  `tol` defines a tolerance (your example is `1e-8`) which measures the difference between successive iterations.  `ii` is a counter variable which is the `i` variable in the sum formula.  Note that I initialize this to 0, but on the first iteration, this will get set to 1.  I also choose to use `ii` instead of `i` as `i` is reserved for the complex variable instead.

Next, we use a `while` loop and we will keep looping as long as the difference between successive iterations is greater than the tolerance.  We save the previous iteration's sum, then compute the next term in the series and accumulate this in the total sum.  We also make sure to increment the counter variable.  This will quit when the difference between successive iterations is less than a certain amount.

I get this for the total number of iterations and the sum once I run this code:

```
>> format long g;
>> s

s =

         0.475415855580831

>> ii

ii =

    18
```

Doing `format long g;` at the beginning will allow us to show more digits of precision.  By default, MATLAB only shows up to 4 decimal places.  The result tells us that this required 18 terms in your summation for it to "stop changing".

Comment: While this answers the exact OP question, it leaves out some important rules.  First, of course, you should prove the series converges :-) .  Next, just because the next term, or the next term difference value, is below some threshold doesn't mean you've achieved any particular accuracy in your answer.  Slowly-converging series are the bane of rookie programmers!  There are theorems on how to estimate (upper/lower bound) the sum of the "tail" of the summation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I gave the benefit of the doubt to  the OP that the series converges and it shares all properties that a convergent series has. I'll update my answer when I have time, but seeing as how the OP has accepted my answer, this seems to have given them enough to move forward.

Comment: Well, they're moving, but not necessarily forward, i.e. towards the correct answer :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft haha! Fair enough!